# Terminating main thread after a certain time in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have created two array of threads using POSIX thread.There are two thread functions student and teacher(I have not shown them here). My sample program is given below. I want to make a time limit(say 10 sec) after which the main thread will automatically exit no matter if the corresponding threads have completed or not. How will I do that?

Sample code fragment:

```
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread1[25];
    pthread_t thread2[6];
    int i;
    int id1[25];   //for students
    int id2[6];   //for teachers

    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
          id1[i]=i;
          id2[i]=i;
          pthread_create(&thread1[i],NULL,student,(void*)&id1[i] );

          if(i<6)
          {
             pthread_create(&thread2[i],NULL,teacher,(void*)&id2[i]);
          }
   }



  for (i=0;i<25;i++)
  {
    pthread_join(thread1[i],NULL);  
     if(i<6)
          {
             pthread_join(thread2[i],NULL);
          }
  }

 return 0;
```

}

What additional things will I have to add to the above code to terminate the main thread after a certain time? (say: 10 seconds)

Comment: Do you want the `main` to terminate as a `return` or `exit` would, such that the whole process is terminated? Or do you want to do `pthread_exit` such that all other threads continue to run?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is pthread timed join. See the snippet below

```
struct timespec
{
    time_t tv_sec;     /* sec */
    long   tv_nsec;    /* nsec */
};

struct timespec ts;

if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) == -1)
{
    printf("ERROR\n");
}


ts.tv_sec += 10; //10 seconds

int st = pthread_timedjoin_np(thread, NULL, &ts); //only wait for 10 seconds
if (st != 0)
{
    printf("ERROR\n");
}
```

For additional info refer the man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_tryjoin_np.3.html

Comment: I think `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` would be more suitable for this usage.

Comment: As the `np` in the name suggests, this is *non portable*, not all POSIX implementations will have this.

Comment: Will I write pthread_timedjoin_np(thread[i], NULL, &ts); inside the loop? what is the necessity of int st here? @knightrider

Comment: @user5216540 yes you have to write it inside the loop. The `st` variable can be used to know whether the thread joined or you reached time-out. If st is `0` then the thread joined. If you dont need to have latter info you can ignore it.

Comment: is there any way to print the remaining time at each moment after starting the program? @knightrider

Comment: @user5216540 when you do `ts.tv_sec += 10;` you are basically creating a time stamp which is +10seconds from `clock_gettime()` (not exactly, but still fine...). Now whenever you want to know the remaining time, you can call again `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts2)`. `ts.tv_sec - ts2.tv_sec` will give you the remaining time (the seconds part)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the whole process to be terminated after `10` seconds of waiting time, you just have to replace the whole `for`-loop with your `pthread_join` calls by a suitable sleep function. You could use `nanosleep`, `clock_nanosleep`, `thrd_sleep` or just

```
sleep(10);
```

After that your `main` function would go out of scope and terminate the process.

Beware, all these functions are sensible to signals that arrive in the middle.

Comment: exactly where in the main function of my code will I use the sleep(10) ? @Jens Gustedt

Comment: @user5216540 You can replace the second for loop nest (the one which contain the `pthread_join` ) with the `sleep(10)`;

Comment: @user5216540, I tried to clarify that, please see my edit.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if the threads *do* all terminate before the 10 seconds is up, you'll still have to wait for the 10 seconds to expire for the main process to finish.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create another thread which will sleep for 10 seconds, then call `exit()` (which will terminate the entire process):

```
void *watchdog(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t all_sigs;

    /* Block all signals in this thread, so that we do not have to
     * worry about the sleep() being interrupted. */ 
    sigfillset(&all_sigs);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &all_sigs, NULL);
    sleep(10);
    exit(0);
    return NULL; /* not reached */
}
```

Create this thread from the main thread after creating the other threads, and detach it:

```
pthread_create(&watchdog_thread, NULL, watchdog, NULL);
pthread_detach(watchdog_thread);
```

Now your process will end either when the main thread finishes after joining the other threads, or when the watchdog thread calls `exit()`, whichever happens first.